# Looking inefficiencies in a JS function

Tags: javascript

I'm working out a codeeval problem that basically gives me an array of strings.  Each string has four integer values that represent two points on Cartesian grid like so, 'a, b, x, y', which may be the same.  The objective is determine the relative direction of the second point in relation to the first point and express that relationship in conventional orienteering terms, e.g., N, NE, E, ..., NW.  If the points are identical, I am to return here.

I was able to solve the problem OK, and the core of my function is here

```js
 var ary = line.split(' '),
     direction = '',
  dif_long = ary[2] - ary[0],
  dif_lat = ary[3] - ary[1];

 if (dif_lat !== 0){direction = (dif_lat > 0) ? 'N' : 'S';}
 if (dif_long !== 0){direction += (dif_long > 0) ? 'E' : 'W';}
 if (direction == '') {direction = 'here';}
 console.log(direction );
```

I've also put up a sample with data on [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SeanOlson/cq8r26am/7/), modified slightly to generate a list rather than console.log.

My problem is that I got zero points for my solution.  This leads me to think that I have a performance problem somewhere.  I would appreciate any constructive suggestions on eliminating inefficiency.

EDIT:  This is not a class assignment.  CodeEval.com is a code challenge site.  It's not a matter of being correct.  It's correct, otherwise the site won't score the solution.

Comment: *I got zero points for my solution* - Who was it that rated your solution? If it was a professor/TA, I'd just go and ask, instead of guessing. In my experience, they often like it if students show an interest in why their solution might be sub-optimal.

Comment: Did you mean to assign to 'respsonse' a second time:  `respsonse = (dif_lat !== 0)`.  Seems like you should be able to end up with something like "falseE" as a result.

Comment: `direction = (dif_lat !== 0){direction = (dif_lat > 0) ? 'N' : 'S';}` <-- this statement is weird.

Comment: @TimoSta CodeEval.com is a code challenge site, not a class, just a game.

Comment: @zerkms -- The logic behind these two comparisons is to compare difference in y and then difference in x.  My reasoning is that this lets be build a string.

Comment: Tell your professor that it's your code and you code how you feel comfortable with and if it works, it works. Unless he has guidelines for you to follow, I really see nothing wrong here.

Comment: if it got zero points, it's probably *incorrect*.

Comment: 'Zero points for my solution'. Solution is already presuming it's correct, but not in the professor's terms. Meaning, there must be some type of guideline  he has to follow, ask your professor what he wants you to do :P

Comment: @Felix, what is stackoverflow if not code review?

Comment: @SeanOlson an oversimplified explanation is: it is a place to ask questions about coding when you get stuck. You want [codereview.stackexchange.com](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Here is your new [code](http://jsfiddle.net/cq8r26am/10/). Your professor should give you bonus points now.

Comment: If your code "works" in the sense that it produces the output you want, then Stack Overflow is most likely not the place to ask about your code.

Comment: @NiCk -- really cool conditional, but why is your approach more efficient?  CodeEvel.com is a code challenge site, I'm not in a class.  Thanks for your work, though :)

Comment: It's to confuse your professor more so maybe he'll give you some more points... ^_^ :D